# How to redirect to another page with html response from ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, redirect

I am getting html document as response from ajax call. I have to do the redirection with this html response like creating the redirection page by using the html response. How can i do that?

Comment: Please use a search engine before you ask a question here. Chances are it's already been asked and you could get the answer much quicker by actually looking for it.

Comment: AJAX is specifically used to stay on the current page, perhaps it's not the tool you should use for this.

Comment: If you are talking about an HTTP GET request, you can simply redirect the user using `window.location.replace('website URL to redirect to')`, no need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  location.href = "https://*/*"